# How can I do to modify this python script to get the same json file without the hightated section?

Tags: python, arrays, json

Currently, I'm trying to import a json file created by the following python script from a csv file.

```
import csv, json

csvFilePath ='USvideos.csv'
jsonFilePath = 'USvideos.json'
data = {}

with open(csvFilePath, encoding = 'utf8') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        video_id = csvRow['video_id']
        data[video_id] = csvRow

with open(jsonFilePath, 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**Problem statement**The problem is that I need to get a json file without the part in parenthesis by modifying the python script which it cames from

```py
("2kyS6SvSYSE": ) {
    "video_id": "2kyS6SvSYSE",
    "trending_date": "17.20.11",
    "title": "WE WANT TO TALK ABOUT OUR MARRIAGE"
},
("1ZAPwfrtAFY":) {
    "video_id": "1ZAPwfrtAFY",
    "trending_date": "17.20.11"
}
```

**Purpose of solving it**
 I need to solve this because I want to import data appropriately in MongoDB

Comment: I suggest writing your `csvRow`s to a `pd.DataFrame` instead of a dictionary. That will allow you to save them to .json without the index column easily by using `.to_json(orient='records')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing as to the output JSON format you need but can you give this a try?

```
import csv, json

csvFilePath ='USvideos.csv'
jsonFilePath = 'USvideos.json'
data = []

with open(csvFilePath, encoding = 'utf8') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        data.append(csvRow)

with open(jsonFilePath, 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works. I have another problem with the same JSON file. It turns out that I need to separate each object just using { } instead of using a coma. Would you suggest me a solution for this, please?

Comment: Unclear what you need. Please post a sample of what you want. Just a few records each of your input and desired output.